# FInding $u(1,1)$ where u(x,t) satisfies nonhomogeneous wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

> $$u_{tt} = 4u_{xx} + \sin(t)x$$
>   $$u(3,t) = u(0,t) = 0$$
>   $$u(x,0) = \sin(\pi x/3)$$
>   $$u_t(x,0) = 3x^3 - 8x^2 $$ find the exact value of $u (1,1) $

My question for this problem is whether it is valid to use d'Alembert's Formula with $c = 2, x = 1, t = 1$ to get the numerical answer

Comment: The equations and the boundary conditions do not seem to be consistent. For example as the source does not vanish at $x=3$ it will be hard (if not impossible) to fulfil $u(3,t)=0$. Also as $u(3,t)=0$, I would suppose that $u_t(3,0)=0$ but you demand that $u_t(3,0)=24$.

Comment: @Fabian: I have updated the question, thank you.

Comment: I am curious about the context of the question. May you explain a little?. I am suspicious as you are about the need to solve the integrals, maybe there is a shorter way. Anyway, the equation is non homogeneous, so you have to add a particular solution to the homogeneous equation ones.